# Scikit-learn SVM classifier dies will "Killed: 9" error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to train classifier and my training date is around 870,000 records and the python script always gets killed after a while calling into classifier.fit(X, Y). I dont see anything in the console except for message "Killed: 9". I am running this on my macbook pro with 16GB memory and training data is pretty small 90 MB.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Code:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

# train_data is list of dictionaries like
# train_data = [{0:"..", 1:"..", 2:".."}, {...}]
# train_labels = [1, 2, 3, ..]
vect = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
X = vect.fit_transform(train_data)
Y = train_labels

print "Training model.."
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, Y) # never goes beyond this line
print "Done"
clf.predict(X_test)
```

Output:

```
Training model..
Killed: 9
```

I tried cutting my dataset into half, but no luck

Comment: have you checked the memory consumption on your os  as the code is running or looked at the logs?

Comment: When is script is running or got killed, I still had around 6 to 7 GB free on my mac. doesn't look like a memory problem. tried searching on google for almost a day and not much luck.

Comment: Might be the case of python 32bit and not 64bit

Comment: what does your log output show? Is it system.log on osx?

Comment: ah, interesting. I see log says "low swap: killing PID (Python)". Not sure why python doesn't go ahead and use rest of the memory available.

Comment: How big is your swap? Also how do you know there was free ram?

Comment: looks like 4MB swap and I was checking ram on some menu bar app I have which show memory usage in realtime (unless that is not really working, my mac might be consuming all memory and swap and killing the process)

Comment: Yes, I think this might be very relevant http://superuser.com/questions/317215/how-to-disable-mac-os-x-from-using-swap-when-there-still-is-inactive-memory/737125#737125

Comment: wow, long and detailed explanation. I tried running same script on a ubuntu machine and it throws "Memory Error", that explains. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. There is not a great deal of info out there related to  these errors.